# How do I setup and .env file and have my code read the .env file?

Tags: heroku, discord, environment-variables, bots

I want to setup and discord bot, but I need some help setting up an .env file and modify my bot code to read the `.env` file. Also, using Heroku to start hosting the bot.

Code for the `main.bot.js`:

```js
    "use strict";
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const discord_js_1 = __importDefault(require("discord.js"));
const builders_1 = require("@discordjs/builders");
const SlashCommand_model_1 = require("./model/SlashCommand.model");
const HelpCommand_command_1 = require("./commands/HelpCommand.command");
const fs_extra_1 = __importDefault(require("fs-extra"));
const BINFlipCommand_command_1 = require("./commands/flip/BINFlipCommand.command");
var client = new discord_js_1.default.Client({ "intents": [discord_js_1.default.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, discord_js_1.default.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, discord_js_1.default.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
client.on('ready', () => __awaiter(void 0, void 0, void 0, function* () {
    var helpcommandbuilder = new builders_1.SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("help")
        .setDescription("Get the list of commands that Project: Scyll has.");
    var binflipcommandbuilder = new builders_1.SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("binflip")
        .setDescription("Finds a BIN snipe on the auction house based on the amount of profit you can make.")
        .addIntegerOption(option => option.setName("profit")
        .setDescription("the amount of profit you would like to make.").setRequired(true));
    SlashCommand_model_1.SlashCommand.CreateSlashCommands([helpcommandbuilder, binflipcommandbuilder]);
}));
client.on('interactionCreate', function (interaction) {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
        if (!interaction.isCommand())
            return;
        new HelpCommand_command_1.HelpCommand(interaction);
        new BINFlipCommand_command_1.BINFlipCommand(interaction);
    });
});
require('dotenv').config()
client.login(process.env.DJS_TOKEN);
```

and also need some help fixing the `.env` thing on this file as well.

```js
"use strict";
var __createBinding = (this && this.__createBinding) || (Object.create ? (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    Object.defineProperty(o, k2, { enumerable: true, get: function() { return m[k]; } });
}) : (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    o[k2] = m[k];
}));
var __setModuleDefault = (this && this.__setModuleDefault) || (Object.create ? (function(o, v) {
    Object.defineProperty(o, "default", { enumerable: true, value: v });
}) : function(o, v) {
    o["default"] = v;
});
var __importStar = (this && this.__importStar) || function (mod) {
    if (mod && mod.__esModule) return mod;
    var result = {};
    if (mod != null) for (var k in mod) if (k !== "default" && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(mod, k)) __createBinding(result, mod, k);
    __setModuleDefault(result, mod);
    return result;
};
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.SlashCommand = void 0;
const discord_js_1 = require("discord.js");
const axios = __importStar(require("axios"));
const rest_1 = require("@discordjs/rest");
const v9_1 = require("discord-api-types/v9");
const fs_extra_1 = __importDefault(require("fs-extra"));
require('dotenv').config()
var token = process.env.DJS_TOKEN;
class SlashCommand {
    constructor(interaction) {
        this.http = axios.default;
        this.interaction = interaction;
        this.command = interaction.commandName;
        this.purple = "#BA55D3";
        this.backtick = "`";
        this.gold = "#d4af37";
        this.red = "#C70039";
    }
    CreateEmbed() {
        return new discord_js_1.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor("Project: Scyll", this.interaction.client.user.avatarURL()).setFooter("Project:Scyll 0.1.0").setTimestamp();
    }
    static CreateSlashCommands(commands) {
        return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
            require('dotenv').config()
            var clientid = process.env.SERVER_CLIENT_ID;
            yield SlashCommand.REST.put(v9_1.Routes.applicationCommands(clientid), { "body": commands });
        });
    }
}
exports.SlashCommand = SlashCommand;
SlashCommand.REST = new rest_1.REST({ "version": "9" }).setToken(token);
```

I put in `client.login(process.env.DJS_TOKEN)` I also did it in Heroku, in the Config Vars

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ...where did this code come from? Did you write this, or is it compiled from another source?

Comment: In any case, the `.env` file isn't magic. You need to read it in somehow. `heroku local` does that automatically, or you can use something like [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). Are you doing either of those things? How are you running this on your development machine?

Comment: I want to setup dotenv

Comment: Okay. Have you read any documentation about [how it works](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#user-content-usage)? We're not here to replace search engines, documentation, or tutorials.

Comment: I put in client.login(process.env.SERVER_BOT_KEY); and the bot still doesn’t go online. I put “dotenv”: “^14.3.0” in my package.json. I also did it in Heroku, in the Config Vars section. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you've updated your code to use `process.env.SERVER_BOT_KEY` and set a `SERVER_BOT_KEY` config var on Heroku, your app should work there. Heroku doesn't need `dotenv` or use an `.env` file.

This won't be enough locally, though. You have installed `dotenv` and created your `.env` file, but it doesn't sound like you've actually [imported and used it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#user-content-usage):

> 2. As early as possible in your application, import and configure dotenv.
>
>    ```js
>    // index.js
>    require('dotenv').config()
>
>    console.log(process.env) // remove this after you've confirmed it working
>    ```

Make sure to `require('dotenv').config()` in your code.

Ideally, that can be done once in a shared startup file but I can't tell from the code you shared above if you have something like that. That code looks like it was generated by a tool of some kind.

Note that your `.env` file should not be tracked. Make sure to add it to your `.gitignore`.

Comment: on heroku, it keeps saying "saved". nothing else. why is the bot not going online. I am about to update the code on the question post, so you can read it.

Comment: @Gurman3756, the word "saved" doesn't appear anywhere in the code you shared so we have no way of knowing what that means. What would that indicate? Can you share the relevant code by updating your question? See [ask].